# retrive minimum maximum values of a ctype

Tags: python, python-3.x

I parse some ASCII text using python which return me strings like:
UI8, SI32, etc...

Based on those strings I need to compute the maximum value of the types and to replace them with following strings:
unsigned char, signed long, etc...

I found in python [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) lib, but i was unable to find how to get maximum\minimum.

Does Python have something exquivalent to `std::numeric_limits` in C++?

Comment: you can try min(),max() from numeric_limits of c++.

Comment: Is `sizeof` on a ctype what you are looking for?

Comment: You can get a tuple containing bounds info for integral `ctypes` from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31340336/4014959).

Comment: related Python issue: [ctypes variable limits](https://bugs.python.org/issue9030)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many such strings are there?  It might be quickest to define them by hand yourself:

```
class MaxVal:
    SI8  = 2 ** 7  - 1
    UI8  = 2 ** 8  - 1
    SI16 = 2 ** 15 - 1
    UI16 = 2 ** 16 - 1
    SI32 = 2 ** 31 - 1
    UI32 = 2 ** 32 - 1
    SI64 = 2 ** 63 - 1
    UI64 = 2 ** 64 - 1
```

Or you could put them in a `dict`.  I put them in static attributes of a `class` because it's about the neatest way of letting you refer to them in a way that "feels like" `enum` constants:

```
print( MaxVal.UI32 )
```

More programmatically, if your type string is a variable, you could use it like this:

```
dt = 'UI32'
print( getattr(MaxVal, dt) )
```

The corresponding `MinVal` definitions are left as an exercise for the reader..